I am not able to uninstall emacs from ubuntu using the terminal?
I am trying to uninstall emacs from my ubuntu system but I am not able to do so. I have run the command sudo apt-get remove --purge emacs. But still, I see emacs present in my system.
I also tried to uninstall using Ubuntu software but it says unable to remove.
NB: I used the sudo apt install emacs yesterday to install emacs. After checking the version using emacs --version, I get emacs GUI 27.1 as output.
How to uninstall emacs from Ubuntu? Is there any way to uninstall emacs using the GUI also??

solved:
sudo apt remove emacs
then
sudo apt autoremove
.. removed both the emacs GUI and emacs  Terminal
